# Mastering Partial Matches in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format, pattern-matching

I am attempting to master the art of telling python how to partially match values.

Here's the scoop. `correct_list` is the 'correct' data frame, while `list_to_be_audited_partial_matches_ok` is the data frame I'd like to ensure is correct.  The issue presented here, though, is tricky: The value in `list_to_be_audited_partial_matches_ok` may or may not be an exact match to the corresponding value in the `correct_list`, if it's in there at all.

The value in `list_to_be_audited_partial_matches_ok` may have some sort of extension to the part within the `correct_list`; the extension could be signaled by a ':' or a "-", for instance.

Here are a few examples of what I need to consider a 'partial match:'

```
correct_list = {'Item': ["ABCDEF", "FEDCBA", "AA-BB-CCCC", "ABCDEFGH-IJK"]}
correct_list = pd.DataFrame(df1)
correct_list

list_to_be_audited_partial_matches_ok = {'Item': ["ABCDEF", "FEDCBA:XA", "AA-BB-CCCC-01", "AA-BB-CCCC-21:ABC", "ABCDEFGH-IJK-1X"]} 
list_to_be_audited_partial_matches_ok = pd.DataFrame(df2)
list_to_be_audited_partial_matches_ok
```

Here is a picture that color codes the partial matches:

[image]

Last bit of request I have is to have a count of all the partial matches listed.

Any ideas on how to partially match these values? Perhaps a new column that displays 'True/False' depending on if there is a partial match or not?

Why wouldn't this work?

Error message I get:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the part of string from the last `-` (priority is given to hyphen, since your examples prove the `:` char can follow the `-` to remove) till end of string, or from the last `:` till end of string, and then check if the strings under the audition match any of the strings in the correct list.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

correct_list = {'Item': ["ABCDEF", "FEDCBA", "AA-BB-CCCC", "ABCDEFGH-IJK"]}
list_to_be_audited_partial_matches_ok = {'Item': ["ABCDEF", "FEDCBA:XA", "AA-BB-CCCC-01", "AA-BB-CCCC-21:ABC", "ABCDEFGH-IJK-1X"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(correct_list)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list_to_be_audited_partial_matches_ok)

pat = fr'^(?:{"|".join(map(re.escape, df1["Item"]))})$'
df2['Audit Result'] = df2['Item'].str.replace(r'-[^-]*$|:[^:]*$', '', regex=True).str.contains(pat)
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
                Item  Audit Result
0             ABCDEF          True
1          FEDCBA:XA          True
2      AA-BB-CCCC-01          True
3  AA-BB-CCCC-21:ABC          True
4    ABCDEFGH-IJK-1X          True
```

The `.str.replace(r'-[^-]*$|:[^:]*$', '', regex=True)` part removes the suffixes, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LApOHI/1). More details:

- `-[^-]*$` - `-` + zero or more chars other than `-` (`[^-]*`) till end of string (`$`)
- `|`
- `:[^:]*$` - `:` + zero or more chars other than `:` (`[^:]*`) till end of string (`$`).

The `.str.contains(pat)` checks if the input string fully matches one of the items in `df1['Item']`. The regex looks like `^(ABCDEF|FEDCBA|AA-BB-CCCC|ABCDEFGH-IJK)$`, see [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/8wNYp0/1).

Comment: How would I also replicate this same process for df1?  When swapping the code, it seems to produce a lot of 'False' values, which wouldn't be correct:


pat = fr'^(?:{"|".join(map(re.escape, df2["Item"]))})$'
df1['Audit Result'] = df1['Item'].str.replace(r'-[^-]*$|:[^:]*$', '', regex=True).str.contains(pat)
df1

Comment: Is a new process needed to check if partial matches exist from df2 to df1 (before we saw if partial matches existed from df1 to df2)

Comment: Example, if 'ZZZ' was submitted into the correct list, there'd be nothing flagging the user to change list_to_be_audited_partial_matches_ok to include this 'ZZZ' value.